# Handler and runnable while device has been turned off (Android)

Tags: android

I created a handler with runnable etc to delay some notifications, very simple.
The first notification has a delay of 1 hour en the second 2 hours etc. But, when the users turns off his the device when the first has fired already, the second one won't be fired anymore... I really need the second and following notifications to be fired, although the user has turned off his device between those times..

How to do this?
 My code for the notifications, do I have to add something?:

```
  final Switch mySwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.theswitch);
        mySwitch.setChecked(myPrefs.getBoolean("switch", false));





        //attach a listener to check for changes in state
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         final boolean isChecked) {


                editor.putBoolean("switch", isChecked);
                editor.commit();

                if (isChecked) {
                    //switch has been switched ON

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
                    Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
                    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
// you can get seconds by adding  "...:ss" to it
                    date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
                    String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

                    Log.w(localTime, "1");


                    if (localTime.equals("08:50") || localTime.equals("08:51") || localTime.equals("08:52") || localTime.equals("08:53") || localTime.equals("08:54") || localTime.equals("08:55") || localTime.equals("08:56")
                            || localTime.equals("08:57") || localTime.equals("08:58") || localTime.equals("08:59") || localTime.equals("09:00") || localTime.equals("09:01") || localTime.equals("09:02") || localTime.equals("09:03")
                            || localTime.equals("09:04") || localTime.equals("09:05") || localTime.equals("09:06") || localTime.equals("09:07") || localTime.equals("09:08") || localTime.equals("09:09") || localTime.equals("09:10")
                            || localTime.equals("09:11") || localTime.equals("09:12") || localTime.equals("09:13") || localTime.equals("09:14") || localTime.equals("09:15") || localTime.equals("09:16") || localTime.equals("09:17")
                            || localTime.equals("09:18") || localTime.equals("09:19") || localTime.equals("09:20") || localTime.equals("09:21") || localTime.equals("09:22") || localTime.equals("09:23") || localTime.equals("09:24")
                            || localTime.equals("09:25") || localTime.equals("09:26") || localTime.equals("09:27") || localTime.equals("09:28") || localTime.equals("09:29") || localTime.equals("09:30") || localTime.equals("09:31")
                            || localTime.equals("09:32") || localTime.equals("09:33") || localTime.equals("09:34") || localTime.equals("09:35") || localTime.equals("09:36") || localTime.equals("09:37") || localTime.equals("09:38")
                            || localTime.equals("09:39") || localTime.equals("09:40") || localTime.equals("09:41") || localTime.equals("09:42") || localTime.equals("09:43") || localTime.equals("09:44") || localTime.equals("09:45")
                            || localTime.equals("09:46") || localTime.equals("09:47") || localTime.equals("09:48") || localTime.equals("09:49") || localTime.equals("09:50") || localTime.equals("09:51") || localTime.equals("09:52")
                            || localTime.equals("09:53") || localTime.equals("09:54") || localTime.equals("09:55") || localTime.equals("09:56") || localTime.equals("09:57") || localTime.equals("09:58") || localTime.equals("09:59")
                            || localTime.equals("10:00") || localTime.equals("10:01") || localTime.equals("10:02") || localTime.equals("10:03") || localTime.equals("10:04") || localTime.equals("10:05") || localTime.equals("10:06")
                            || localTime.equals("10:07") || localTime.equals("10:08") || localTime.equals("10:09") || localTime.equals("10:10") || localTime.equals("15:07")) {

                        Log.w("It is between", "those times");


                        boolean beenfired2 = myPrefs.getBoolean("beenfired", false);


                        if (beenfired2 != true) {

                            Log.w("yes", "it is not equal to true");
                            // day 1

                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 3600000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 7200000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 7200000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 14400000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 18000000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 21600000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 25200000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 28800000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 32400000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 36000000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 39600000);

                            // day 2
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 90000000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 97200000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 104400000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 111600000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 118800000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 126000000);


                            // day 3
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 180000000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 190800000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 201600000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 212400000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 212400000);

                            // day 4
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 270000000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 284400000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 298800000);

                            // day 5
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 367200000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 388800000);

                            // day 6
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 460800000);
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 475200000);

                            // day 7
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 554400000);


                            // day 8
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mClickRunnable, 648000000);



                            beenfired = true;
                            editor.putBoolean("beenfired", beenfired);
                            editor.commit();


                        } else {

                            Log.w("else", "else");


                        }

                    } else {

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Inlopen.this);

                        // set title
                        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alarm kan niet worden ingeschakeld");

                        // set dialog message
                        alertDialogBuilder
                                .setMessage("U kunt het alarm alleen inschakelen tussen 9:00 en 10:00 's ochtends.")
                                .setCancelable(false)

                                .setNegativeButton("Oke", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                                        // the dialog box and do nothing


                                        mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                                        editor.putBoolean("switch", false);
                                        editor.commit();
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                        // create alert dialog
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                        // show it
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }


                } else {
                    //switch has been switched OFF
                    beenfired = false;

                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mClickRunnable);
                    mHandler.removeMessages(0);

                    editor.putBoolean("beenfired", beenfired);
                    editor.commit();

                    editor.putBoolean("switch", false);
                    editor.commit();


                }

            }
        });


    }


    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mClickRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(Inlopen.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconsmall)
                            .setContentTitle("DM Voet App")
                            .setContentText("Uw moet uw voeten controleren!");
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

From the Document:
"The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running."

Comment: could you give an example of this?

Comment: Try this link http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/     Also https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: This is not exactly what I mean, I just want to delay the notifications without the problems with the user turning off his device